# How to extract values within a span

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a very complex situation.  To reduce it to its basics ...
First of this is a aspx csharp jquery ajax app

I am populating a  with textboxes and other input controls at runtime using ajax sending html from the codebehind to the page and laying the html into a span.
Now I need to grab the values of these input control.  I do not know in advance what these controls are except that they are one of several (input- text, checkbox, radio).

How can I access all input values with a span in this case.  The span could be another delimiter and I tried  but my master page has a form and it is not (I am guessing) allowing me to place a form here.

My objective is to grab the values and return them via ajax and use them as search criteria to my search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var inputValArray = [];
$('[span selector] input').each(function() { // $('[span selector] > input') for direct children only
   inputValArray.push($(this).val());
});
```

`span selector` could be `id` or a `css class` on the span. If you can update your question with some HTML or more info as to how you can distinguish this span, I can update my answer.

Comment: This is what I need.  Great.  Can I ask one more piece?  How can I get the names of the control?  I need to build a json string so I am trying to place them rather in a string than an array.

Comment: `this` is the dom element. So `this.name` would give the name.

Comment: hmmm the inputarray worked but this comes back with undefined&   $("#spanSearchCriteria input").each(function () {
 //inputValArray.push($(this).val());
 myval += $(this).val() + "&";
});

Comment: Make sure you initialize `myval= '';` before the loop.

Comment: my html shows this: <input type="text" value="" name="Price"> but this $("#spanSearchCriteria input").each(function () {
 //inputValArray.push($(this).val());
 myval += $(this).name + "=" + $(this).val() + "&";
 });   returns "undefinedundefined=123&"

Comment: ok your suggestion of the initializer got rid of the first undefined but I can't grab the name

Comment: I do not know what jsfiddle is - I just looked at the site and I have never used it

Comment: Looks like you're not getting the name. Try this: `$(this).attr('name');`

Comment: That did it.  You have been VERY helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite follow your question; your situation must be very complex. In jQuery, you can use a selector like

```
var inputControls = $("#spanId :input")
```

to obtain a reference to all input controls inside your span. You could then use .each to process each one in turn.